# Flex Actionscript project swf is not working after export the release build

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, release, addchild

I tried to built a project with AS3 only in Flex. When I run the project in flex, everything looks fine, but when I export the release build, the images that are supposed to be added are gone. I appreciate if someone can help me about it.

```
      init();

        public function init(loadedVideoCount:Number):void{

                    singleHolder=new singleVideoCont();
                    singleHolder.x=loadedVideoCount*singleHolder.width+2;
                    singleHolder.y=6;
                    singleHolder.buttonMode=true;
                    addChild(singleHolder);
                    this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);

                    showTn();

                }



    private function showTn():void{

            imgLoader = new Loader();
            imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(_tnPath));
                                            imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onProgress);
imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImgLoaded);



    }           



    private function onImgLoaded(event:Event):void {
        singleHolder.progBar.alpha = 0;
           var image:Bitmap = imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.content as Bitmap;

                image.width=TN_WIDTH;
                image.height=TN_HEIGHT;
                image.x=3;
                image.y=3;
                singleHolder.addChild(image); //this line work when I run the project inside flex but the images are gone when I test my release build...

                        imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onProgress);
                        imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onImgLoaded);
                        //imgLoader = null;
                    }
```

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute URLs to identify these images?

Comment: I got those images from youtube search api..I assume it returned a http address (url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a trace statement to look at the value of _tnPath and add this listener to see if you get any errors:

```
 imgLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler );

 private function errorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent ):void
 {
    trace( "ioErrorHandler: " + event );
 }
```